# I can't view a pdf file in the pdf.js library

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

My problem is that when I display the PDF file in my following code, the Arabic language is irregular or incomprehensible, even though I made sure that I chose the latest version of the pdf.js library, and I made sure that there are no errors in the code, and I made sure that the encryption of the PDF file PDF is UTF-8 and I asked chatgpt and it did not give me a solution. Does anyone have any solution?

```
try {
    var url = document.getElementById("source").innerHTML;
var numberOfCanvases = 1;
let pdfDoc = null,
pageNum = 1,
pageIsRendering = false,
pageNumIsPending = null;
const scale = 1.5;
const renderPage = num => {
    pageIsRendering = true;
    var pager = num;
    var canvas = document.querySelector(`.page-${num}`);
    pdfDoc.getPage(pager).then(page => {
        const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale });
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;
        var renderCtx = {
            canvasContext: canvas.getContext('2d'),
            viewport
        };
        page.render(renderCtx).promise.then(() => {
        pageIsRendering = false;
        if (pageNumIsPending !== null) {
            renderPage(pageNumIsPending);
            pageNumIsPending = null;
        }
        });
    });
};
pdfjsLib.getDocument(url).promise.then(pdfDoc_ => {
    pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;
    numberOfCanvases = pdfDoc.numPages;
    console.log(numberOfCanvases)
    var pageS = 1;
    for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfCanvases; i++){
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.classList.add(`page-${pageS}`);
        canvas.classList.add(`pdf-view`);
        canvas.id = `page-${pageS}`;
        document.querySelector(".body main .center-column.cana").appendChild(canvas);
        renderPage(pageS);
        pageS++;
    }
    $(".spinerIII").remove();
    console.log(read);
    if(read == 1){
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(localStorage.getItem(`SaveProgressPush-${url}`) != null){
                window.scrollTo(0,localStorage.getItem(`SaveProgressPush-${url}`));
            }
        },300)
    }
});
} catch (error) {
    $(".spinerIII .spinner > div").css({
        "border":"5px solid red"
    });
    $(".spinerIII p").html("An error occurred click on the cube")
}
```

HTML script source

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/3.11.174/pdf.min.js"></script>
```

I tried a lot to find a solution. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?